# Android MapView attribution is hidden

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a MapView in my application and I know that Google requires showing the attribution.  However I want to show a CardView on top of the map as seen in the Google Street View app :

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HomQ_aI9pJlFVvT-YW_Vp71hpo6n90C_BRUaSJYnRuIOLtvxK8QxaXC03_NngbBqJCo=h900-rw

When I display my card views, they cover up the map attribution and I can't figure out how to make it visible.  Does anyone know if there is a way to move it or if Google was only able to get around it for their app since they own the maps?

Edit: To make it more clear, when I try the same thing, the "Google" text always appears on the bottom of the MapView.  But somehow Street View has made the text appear high enough above the bottom so that the cards don't cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually adjust the map padding (based on which UI controls you're showing/hiding). The map padding will move the attribution text based on the supplied values.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setPadding(int, int, int, int)